# iPhone not resizing my website to its viewport size (non responsive)

Tags: mobile, web, resize, viewport

Am trying to resolve an issue with my website , which when opened in iphone 4s is failing to re-size to viewport.

The website is not responsive and the expected result in mobile device is to have the complete website re-sized to the viewport. Below are the things i tried

- No viewport meta tag set : Works in Android, Not working in iphone.
- Added viewport with width = device-width : Works in Android, Notworking in iphone.
- Added vieport with width=980 : Works in Android,Not working in iphone.
- Added viewport with width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0 : Works in Android, Not working
  in iphone.

Am i missing somthing!!!

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1., user-scalable=no, target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```